# How would I write a Java regex that gets the contents of a <script> tag?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, gwt

I'm trying to integrate analytics into my GWT application. To do this, I'm calling a service that returns a String of HTML that needs to be parsed and eval'ed.

I need a regex that looks for  and grabs either 1) the body of the tag or 2) the contents of the "src" attribute. I want to eval both of these with JavaScript. I'm happy with assuming that if a "src" attribute exists, the body can be ignored.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: This question is really confusing, Java != JavaScript

Comment: I need to do the parsing of HTML with Java. After getting the JavaScript, I'll eval it. Oh, and I'm using GWT, so Java /is/ JavaScript. ;-)

Comment: It seems like there's got to be a better way to do what you're trying to do.  What you propose is a very unnatural pairing (regex to find js tag & then eval while using GWT)

Comment: Someone needs to tag this with 'GWT' or 'Google Web Toolkit'.  Also, please make it more clear in the question that you are using GWT.  Otherwise, this question doesn't make much sense (better ways to do the same thing in a js context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
    final String srcOne = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script src=\"http://test.com/some.js\"/>\r\n</head></html>";
    final String srcTwo = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script src=\"http://test.com/some.js\"></script>\r\n</head></html>";
    final String tag = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script>\r\nfunction() {\r\n\talert('hi');\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n</head></html>";
    final String tagAndSrc = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script src=\"http://test.com/some.js\">\r\nfunction() {\r\n\talert('hi');\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n</head></html>";
    final String[] tests = new String[] {srcOne, srcTwo, tag, tagAndSrc, srcOne + srcTwo, tag + srcOne + tagAndSrc};

    final String regex = "<script(?:[^>]*src=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"][^>]*>|[^>]*>([^<]*)</script>)";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    for (int testNumber = 0; testNumber < tests.length; ++testNumber) {
        final String test = tests[testNumber];
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("TEST " + testNumber + ": " + test);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("GROUP 1: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("GROUP 2: " + matcher.group(2));
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

That being said, you would probably be better off using something like [Tag Soup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) if it is at all possible.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer since it does what I originally wanted. Also, laz provided me with the secondary answer (below) that I needed for the final solution.

Comment: Is that correct? I would think the last peren should be inside the </script> tag like this:<script(?:[^>]*src=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"][^>]*>|[^>]*>([^<]*))</script> because I believe script tags not specified always with a closing node, not shorthand, so </script>, never />

Comment: You are technically correct, which is the best kind of correct of course, except that HTML in the wild can certainly be malformed and if a browser can render it (or ever did), be assured someone once wrote it that way! Since Matt seems to have controlled the HTML being parsed though, he might not have needed to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Must it be a regex? You can use the DOM to obtain such information, here is a trivial example of getting the contents of the BODY tag, you could apply it to whatever you like:

```
function test(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    alert(body.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes! Parsing non-regular strings with regular expressions is WRONG!

Comment: +1.  I love regex, but use the right tool for the job.  regex is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: While I agree in principle, he's trying to do this via the GWT which uses java to create javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
String ScriptPattern = "<script\b([^>]+)>(.*?)</script>"    
Pattern ScriptRegex = Pattern.compile(ScriptPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The regex uses the lazy star quantifier and should work in most cases but it could certainly be improved upon.

It will match in $1 the attributes of the script tag, and in $2 the body.  You can then check for the **src** attribute in $1 (if it's not empty).

Answer (score 0):

To match the body of the tag, you can try something like

```
<script[^>]*?>(.*?)</script>
```

which you want to match case-insensitively. Works assuming there is no "" appearing in the actual script body and no ">" in the attributes for the  tag. You can add whitespace globbers to the regexp to make it more robust. Note the use of .*? to make sure the scanning stops at the first closing  tag.

To add the src attribute, you can try

```
<script[^>]*?(src="([^"]*)")?[^>]*?>(.*?)</script>
```

and use the second submatch to get 'src', and third to get the body. Again, you might want to add whitespace globbers.

But would be best off by running the thing through a proper HTML/XML/SGML parser, because regexps can blow up in special cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<script>(.*)</script>|<script src="(.*)">.*</script>
```

to start with. You may need to customize it a bit to

1. accept the src attribute with single quotes or without quotes.
2. ignore white between the '<script' and '>'

You also must use the [DOTALL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode to ensure the **.** captures newlines.

Comment: Agreed. There are many cases it won't handle (like the type attribute of the script tag). I suggested this as a start to build from.

Comment: and it will match everything between first <script> and last </script> which wouldn't work nicely when there are multiple scripts on the page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great suggestions everyone. I quickly discovered it's not possible to use Java's Regex API in GWT and was able to do what I wanted with JSNI.

```
public static native String evalJS(Element e) /*-{
    var scripts = e.getElementsByTagName("script");

    for (i=0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        // if src, eval it, otherwise eval the body
        if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {
            eval(scripts[i].getAttribute("src")); // silently fails here
        } else {
            eval(scripts[i].innerHTML); // this works
        }
    }
}-*/;
```

Unfortunately, I ran into additional issues as documented in the following thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/ac2589369ddec8a3

Comment: I guessing that the call to eval(scripts[i].getAttribute("src")) doesn't not load the URL that src="" points to. It is simply trying to execute the actual URL string as JavaScript. You need to figure out how to load the contents of that URL and eval it.

Comment: Ugh, I = I'm and doesn't not = does not

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It allowed me to solve my problem. Here's the solution I came up with:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/msg/0d076f647a4472bc